# Catch general header status code when load image

Tags: javascript, get

I use following code to load an image:

`var image = document.images[0];
 var downloadingImage = new Image();
 downloadingImage.src = "some url";`

I have to use General Headers status code to continue process load fail. I can see General Headers status code in chrome developer tools. But how can I get that status code in my javascript code? Thank you.

Comment: Does that mean I can not get header info with my code?

Comment: I do not think you can get the header information getting the image this way. But you can detect if the image failed to load like this http://jsfiddle.net/adfw8s64/

Comment: You genius! Thanks your code